# how to toggle between npx create-react-app options?

Tags: next.js

I'm in the process of creating a new NextJs app.  I'm using the npm create-react-app cmd and the resulting console output is prompting me with Yes/No options where either Yes or No is underlined for each question.

Is there a way to toggle between these options?  Tab, ctl-tab and clicking on options doesn't do anything.  Pressing Y or N on the keyboard doesn't appear to do anything. Not sure if those options are hard-coded?  Not sure if I've encountered console output in the past that was unintuitive for selection like this.

Answer (score 8):

Ah figured it out.  I typically use git bash for my console, but that doesn't work for the Yes/No implementation used by NextJs.  However, creating the app in via cmd prompt works as expected

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new NextJS app via the CLI you can use this command:

`npx create-next-app@latest`

Then to select the options you can use left and right arrows on your keyboard if prompted

Comment: when i press the left and right arrow keys on my keyboard, they have no visual impact to what is displayed in the console window